# Integral over a sphere spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus

Any idea for solving this?

Compute the integral of $((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2)^{-1/2}$ over the sphere of radius $R$ centered at the origin. Hint: Spherical coordinates.

I don't know how to make the transformation in order to obtain an "easier" problem.

Thanks everyone

Comment: There's no good way to do this. By symmetry, you can reduce to the case where $a=b=0$.  Do you know whether $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is less than or greater than $R^2$?

Comment: Yes, the point $(a,b,c)$ is exterior to the sphere.

Comment: OK, put the point at $(0,0,C)$, use spherical coordinates, and use the law of cosines to rewrite that denominator. Have fun!

Comment: How can I take this point? I don`t understand the symmetry you're talking about.

Comment: why not shift the origin to $(a, b, c )$ and then use spherical coodinates?

Comment: @vidyarthi: Because the equation of the sphere becomes pretty horrid at that juncture. ... user106153, you have rotational symmetry for the sphere, so you lose nothing by taking the point to be on the $z$-axis at the same distance from the center of the sphere as $(a,b,c)$. Draw a picture.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you mean integration over the two-dimensional sphere of radius $R$ (with respect to area measure) or over the full ball of radius $R$. In any case put $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=:\rho$. Then you may assume that  $(a,b,c)=(0,0,\rho)$, since everything is rotationally symmetric with respect to the axis through $O$ and $(a,b,c)$. Now use spherical coordinates $(r,\phi,\theta)$, and distinguish the cases $\rho<R$ and $\rho>R$.